Trivial Mathematica integral on a cube not computing
I was trying to evaluate some intergal over some cube with variable side length, but for some reason Mathematica spit out the input. The interand was sufficiently nice that I couldn't believe it didn't have a closed form solution, moreover it took only a few seconds. I thought my syntax was wrong, so I tried integrating the constant 1. And to my surprise it still does not work. If I substitute the side length with a number it works, but for some reason with some paramenter it doesn't. I try using
Integrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, Cube[l] ], Assumptions -> l > 0]

and it doesn't work, it just answers with the input. If instead I put a number $n$ it gives the obvious correct answer $n^3$. What is happening?

Integrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, Cube[1]]] gives me the answer 1.  I think the problem is that Mathematica doesn't like a symbolic size for the cube.

Yes, if instead of a symbol I use an explicit number there are no problems. However, I have used symbolic sizes for the radius of a ball for example, and there are no problems for that

@tommy1996q, I think you've found another bug. Note Integrate[1, Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[-{l, l}, {l, l}]],   Assumptions -> l > 0]  and Integrate[1, Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[-{l, l}, {l, l}]],   Assumptions -> l > 0]  and RegionMeasure[Cube[l]]  all work as expected.

Integrate[1,{x,-l/2,l/2},{y,-l/2,l/2},{z,-l/2,l/2}] Then estimate the amount of your time spent fighting how to do all this abstractly versus the amount of your time spent doing this concretely.

@Bill already done "your" way in fact! I just didn't understand why "Cube" wasn't working

@CraigCarter if Mathematica returns an integral unevaluated, that isn't really a bug.  It hasn't given you a wrong answer.  So I think this is an "opportunity for improvement" rather than a bug.

Use Cuboid instead.  Integrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, Cuboid[{0,0,0},{l,l,l}] ]]  (* l^3  *)

Interestingly: Volume[Cube[l]]gives l^3!

@Bill Bill, agreed. But, the OP was getting a 0 when that certainly wasn’t correct.  It would be better if it returned the  unevaluated integral.
